# How to tell to client that Django web application is in healthy state or not (status 200)

Tags: django, rest, web, django-rest-framework

I have written a Django web application and also supported REST API to get JSON response.

Now I want to write some health endpoint ( some url ) which is when used, my django web application should tell whether or not it is in healthy state.

Example, If my Django application is not running ( web server is down ), then if a rest api client tries accessing the health endpoint (URL) and it should get response telling application is not healthy.

On the other hand if application is running/up ( web server is up ) then accessing the health endpoint will show message that application is healthy.

Is it doable in Django ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If web server is down, client can not get response from server with status 200.